# Export armature DAE -> glTF rotates mesh 90 degrees

Tags: mesh, export, edit-mode, gltf, dae

To reproduce:

- [Download DAE](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shasaur/babylonjs-playground/master/Breathing%20Idle.dae)
- Open in Blender
- Export to glTF (default settings)
- Open exported glTF in Blender
- Click on mesh
- Go into edit mode
- See that it is rotated 90 degrees around the X axis

Comment: What Blender version? Doesn't happen for me with 2.91.

Comment: I'm running 2.82, I can try updating

Comment: glTF importer's skinning improved significantly in 2.83.

Comment: Ah, yeah I just tried updating and it looks fixed. Thanks so much for pointing this out!

Comment: You can leave it as a comment and I'll accept it as the answer @scurest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to upgrade Blender from 2.82. 2.83 had big improvements in skinning for the glTF importer.

By the way, if you ever have issues with how a skinned mesh looks in edit mode, you can also try toggling the "Guess Original Bind Pose" option on the glTF import screen.